# StepVerifier in unit tests can't see context written asynchronously

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm struggling with tests of WebFilter that uses flatMap and data from it to write something to context.

Here is simplified version of that WebFilter:

```
@Component
@Order(105)
public class EntitlementsFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, @NonNull WebFilterChain chain) {
        ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
            return service.getAuthorization()
                    .flatMap(authorization -> chain
                            .filter(exchange)
                            .contextWrite(ctx -> ctx.put("authorization", authorization))
                    );
    }
}
```

The test for this Filter works, but stops working when Test class is annotated with @SpringBootTest

I've created a small reproducible test example to demonstrate this:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class FooTest {

    @Test
    void test() {
        StepVerifier.create(Mono.just(1)
                        .flatMap(a -> Mono.just(2).contextWrite(ctx -> ctx.put("foo", "boo"))))
                .expectAccessibleContext()
                .then()
                .expectNext(2)
                .expectAccessibleContext()
                .contains("foo", "boo")
                .then()
                .verifyComplete();
    }
}
```

The test fails with:

Expected value boo for key foo, key not present
Context: Context0{}
Captured at: scalarSubscription(1)

but if I remove @SpringBootTest annotation it works.

It seems that this annotation is preventing StepVerifier to wait for flatMap to resolve.

Versions of dependencies that may be relevant:

```
'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:2.7.5'
'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.7.5'
'io.projectreactor:reactor-test:3.5.5' (also tried with 3.4.7)
```

Comment: Can you make a github repository? Because, My fast test is work with/without @SpringBootTest annotation and other situations.

Comment: yes, i can confirm, test passes with-/out spring-boot, ... but `EntitlementsFilter` is not even compil-able...